# How to proxying functions on a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am newbie about javascript.So I do not know what is the name of I looking for and How do I do it?

After you read question if you thing question title is wrong, you should change title.

I am using console.log for debugging but this is causing error if browser IE. I made below function for this problem.

```
var mylog=function(){
   if (devmode && window.console){
      console.log(arguments);
   }
};

mylog("debugging");
```

Now I want to use all console functions without error and I can do that as below.

```
var myconsole={
   log:function(){
        if (devmode && window.console){
          console.log(arguments);
       }
   }
   ,error:function(){
        if (devmode && window.console){
          console.error(arguments);
       }
   }

  ...
  ...
  ...


};
```

But I do not want to add all console functions to myconsole object severally.
I can do that in PHP with below code.

```
class MyConsole
{
  function __call($func,$args)
  {
     if ($devmode && function_exists('Console')){
        Console::$func($args); // Suppose that there is Console class.
     }   
  }
}

MyConsole::warn("name",$name);
MyConsole::error("lastname",$lastname);
```

This is possible with `__noSuchMethod__` method but this is specific to only firefox.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that in JavaScript, the language doesn't have support for the "no such method" concept.

Two options for you:

### Option 1:

Use strings for your method name, e.g.:

```
function myconsole(method) {
    var args;

    if (devmode && window.console) {
        args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, 1);
        window.console[method].apply(window.console, args);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
myconsole("log", "message");
myconsole("error", "errormessage");
```

The meat of `myconsole` is here:

```
args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, 1);
window.console[method].apply(window.console, args);
```

The first line copies all of the arguments supplied to `myconsole` except the first one (which is the name of the method we want to use). The second line retrieves the function object for the property named by the string in `method` from the `console` object and then calls it via the JavaScript [`apply` function](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.3), giving it those arguments.

### Option 2:

A second alternative came to me which is best expressed directly in code:

```
var myconsole = (function() {

    var methods = "log debug info warn error assert clear dir dirxml trace group groupCollapsed groupEnd time timeEnd profile profileEnd count exception table".split(' '),
        index,
        myconsole = {},
        realconsole = window.console;

    for (index = 0; index < methods.length; ++index) {
        proxy(methods[index]);
    }

    function proxy(method) {
        if (!devmode || !realconsole || typeof realconsole[method] !== 'function') {
            myconsole[method] = noop;
        }
        else {
            myconsole[method] = function() {
                return realconsole[method].apply(realconsole, arguments);
            };
        }
    }

    function noop() {
    }

    return myconsole;
})();
```

Then you just call `log`, `warn`, etc., on `myconsole` as normal.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder.Your suggestion is good.There is different methods for do this ?

Comment: @mesuutt: I came up with a second idea, which I've added. In the future, ECMAScript6 (when it happens) may make it possible to avoid having that list of names, via a feature called "proxies". But it's not well-defined yet, and of course ECMAScript6 is some time off, and then waiting for old browsers to die is even longer away...

Comment: I was looking for exactly that your second alternate function :) Thanks

Comment: @mesuutt: Good deal, glad that helped!